# Why do I have to do a fitBounds twice before fitBounds works with @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I have a basic React Maps POC that shows Pins of users on the map, I use React Hooks to set those users and locations on load and everything works well, when I inject a new user *Inject User button* to the state and then do a fitBounds, the map updates with the new user and fits the bounds with that new user.

When I click on the *Fetch Users* button I update the state to the initial set of users and I do a fitBounds, the last user then gets removed from the map and the state but the bounds aren't updated. Only when I click on *Fetch Users* for the second time then only does fitBounds work.

Link to my repository: https://github.com/ArrieAgilite/react-maps-poc.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All forms of setters, that change the state are async. This means they actually run after your method using them finishes.

You are setting state in getMyPlaces(). So the `fitBounds` inside the onClick of the button

```
onClick={() => {
   getMyPlaces();
   fitBounds(mapRef)
}}
```

runs BEFORE the state is actually set.

You should add an effect, that triggers the fitBounds after changes to the places, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fitBounds();
}, [places])
```